# send email using system.web.Mail in asp.net without saving attachment on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

When I tried to send Email using system.web.mail I can send the mail successfully without attachment.
 But when I tried to send mail using attachment I am getting error : Invalid access (access to the specific directory is denied). Because I am saving the file on server to send mail.

Now My solution for this to send mail using attachment without storing the file on server

Please some one here help me send mail using system.web with attachment without storing the file on server

```
Below is my previous old code



 public void SendMailtoRecruitment()
        {
            string filePath = FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            StringBuilder sbEmailBody = new StringBuilder();

            string strFileName = "";


            sbEmailBody.Append("Dear Recruitment Team" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEmailBody.Append("The application is received from the following candidate for the job mentioned in the subject.");
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");

            sbEmailBody.Append("Position Id:" + JobId);
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");

            sbEmailBody.Append("Position Description:" + jobrole);
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");

            sbEmailBody.Append("Candidate First Name :" + First.Text);
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");
            sbEmailBody.Append("Candidate Last  Name :" + Last.Text);
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");
            sbEmailBody.Append("Candidate Email :" + TxtEmailAddress.Text);
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");

            sbEmailBody.Append("Candidate Contact No :" + Contact.Text);
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");
            sbEmailBody.Append("Reply the Status of the Application as early as posible");


            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");
            sbEmailBody.Append("\n");


            sbEmailBody.Append("\n" + "Sri Tech Consulting" + "\n");
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            String fileName = FileUpLoad1.FileName;
            if (FileUpLoad1.PostedFile != null)
            {
                /* Get a reference to PostedFile object */
                HttpPostedFile attFile = FileUpLoad1.PostedFile;
                /* Get size of the file */
                int attachFileLength = attFile.ContentLength;
                /* Make sure the size of the file is > 0  */
                if (attachFileLength > 0)
                {
                    strFileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.FileName);
                  //  FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
                    MailAttachment attach = new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath(strFileName),MailEncoding.Base64);
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attach);




                }


                // mail.Attachments.Add(attach);
            //  mail.To = "Recruitment@btc-india.in";
             mail.To = "rajesh@btc-india.in";

                mail.From = "noreply@btc-india.in";

                mail.Subject = "Job Application : "+ jobrole;

                mail.Body = sbEmailBody.ToString();

                mail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1");   //basic authentication

                mail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", "noreply@btc-india.in"); //set your username here

                mail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", "Anuhya@1999");       //set your password here

                SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "208.91.198.171";

                SmtpMail.Send(mail);

            }
        }
```

Comment: try to add attachment from stream http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/268/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-mvc   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/sending-an-e-mail-with-attachment-using-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: Here I am using MailAttchment.    system.web.mail
I cant use attachment because namespaces  both were different  system.net.mail

Comment: You may be searching [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Attach-files-to-email-without-storing-on-disk-using-ASP.Net-FileUpload-Control.aspx)

Comment: its working only with gmail not working with  other domains like

noreply@companydomain.com